# Difference between state space and transfer function model response (in Simulink)

Tags: matlab, filter-design, transfer-function, state-space

Why I get a different response from the same system (e.g. three phase inverter with LC filter) in state space form and in transfer function (Laplace) form when using the same PI controller values ($K_p$ and $T_i$)?

First I start with differential equations for each phase $a$, $b$ and $c$ to get state space model

\begin{align}\frac{dx}{dt}&=Ax+Bu\\y&=Cx+Du\end{align}

Than an $abc/dq$ transformation is applied (to get coupled relationship between $d$ and $q$ frame). Finally separate equations for $d$ and $q$ frame can be written and transformed to Laplace. From there I can get control scheme and calculate $K_p$ and $T_i$ to get desired overshoot and settling time.

But when I use the same $K_p$ and $T_i$ in the state space model I get extremely noisy and oscillatory response. My question is why is that? I read previous similar question “[Control theory: Laplace versus state space representation](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=265934)” and the difference is that the transfer function neglects initial states.

Additional question: how to then calculate PI controller values when using state space form to get desired overshoot and settling time?

Comment: Is your starting state different for the two? Is the steady state response the same?

Comment: @Phonon Starting state is the same (simulation is done in the same file). Steady state response is also "the same", only state space is extremely noisy (see http://tinypic.com/r/2v0mxpv/5). If I make Ti 100 times higher, I can get the same response, but the controller is than slow (and I don't get desired overshoot and settling time)